# Problems with JSON in Flutter

Tags: json, http, flutter, dart

I have a problem with a JSON that I take from a URL. Here is the link: https://bigpanda.cern.ch/api/grafana?table=running&groupby=time,resourcesreporting&field=wavg_hs06&resourcetype=GRID|hpc|cloud.
I'm trying to get the values ​​of "values" and "resources reporting". I looked on the internet how it turned out and came to the following conclusion that the PODO class file should look like this, but it gives me an error.

**DATA CLASS**

```
class Data {
  List<Result> result;

  Data({this.result});

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Data(
      result: List<Result>.from(json["results"].map((x) => Result.fromJson(x))),
    );
  }
}

class Result {
  int id;
  List<Series> series;



  Result({this.id, this.series});

  factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Result(
      id: json["statement_id"],
      series: List<Series>.from(json["results"].map((x) => Series.fromJson(x))),
      // series: List<Series>.from(json["series"].map((x) => Series.fromJson(x))),
    );
  }
}

class Series {
  String name;
  List<Values> values;

  Series({this.name, this.values});

  factory Series.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Series(
      name: json["resourcesreporting"],
      values: List<Values>.from(json["values"].map((x) => Values.fromJson(x))),
    );
  }
}

class Values {
  List<num> listTime = [];
  List<num> listValue = [];

  Values(this.listTime, this.listValue);

  Values.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    List<List<num>> prices = json['values'];
    for (var price in prices) {
      listTime.add(price[0]);
      listValue.add(price[1]);
    }
  }
}
```

I use the following library to take JSON itself since I had errors related to SSL certificates: https://pub.dev/packages/requests. 
This is the code I'm trying to get "values" from the URL.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    fetchJson();
    super.initState();
  }

  void fetchJson() async {
    var r = await Requests.get(widget.data_url, verify: false);
    r.raiseForStatus();
    var dataChartJson = r.json();
    print(dataChartJson.runtimeType);
    Data data = new Data.fromJson(dataChartJson);
    print(data.result[0]);
  }
```

Here I also share the mistake that comes out of me.

```
I/flutter ( 5167): _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>
E/flutter ( 5167): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 5167): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 5167): Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => Series)
E/flutter ( 5167): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter ( 5167): #1      new Result.fromJson (package:adc_monitoring/model/chart/data.dart:24:49)
E/flutter ( 5167): #2      new Data.fromJson.<anonymous closure> (package:adc_monitoring/model/chart/data.dart:8:67)
E/flutter ( 5167): #3      MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:417:29)
E/flutter ( 5167): #4      ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:346:26)
E/flutter ( 5167): #5      new List.from (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:54:19)
E/flutter ( 5167): #6      new Data.fromJson (package:adc_monitoring/model/chart/data.dart:8:13)
E/flutter ( 5167): #7      _MultipleChartsState.fetchJson (package:adc_monitoring/screens/big_panda/multiple_charts.dart:57:21)      
E/flutter ( 5167): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5167): #8      _MultipleChartsState._ackAlert.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:adc_monitoring/screens/big_panda/multiple_charts.dart:89:17)
E/flutter ( 5167): #9      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:706:14)
E/flutter ( 5167): #10     _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:789:36)
E/flutter ( 5167): #11     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter ( 5167): #12     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:486:11)
E/flutter ( 5167): #13     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:264:5)
E/flutter ( 5167): #14     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:199:7)
E/flutter ( 5167): #15     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:467:9)
E/flutter ( 5167): #16     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:76:12)
E/flutter ( 5167): #17     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:117:9)
E/flutter ( 5167): #18     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379:8)
E/flutter ( 5167): #19     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:115:18)
E/flutter ( 5167): #20     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:7)
E/flutter ( 5167): #21     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:19)
E/flutter ( 5167): #22     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter ( 5167): #23     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter ( 5167): #24     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter ( 5167): #25     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter ( 5167): #26     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1138:13)
E/flutter ( 5167): #27     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
E/flutter ( 5167): #28     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:933:7)
E/flutter ( 5167): #29     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:273:10)
E/flutter ( 5167): #30     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:182:5)
E/flutter ( 5167):
```

Here I also share the mistake that comes out of me. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: To help improve the odds of getting answers to your question, take a look at the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask